# Plot GAM relation between variable and estimated variable

Tags: r

I am running a GAM model like this:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
```

I know I can plot the outcome like so:

```
plot(b,pages=1)
plot(b, select = 1)
plot(b, select = 2)
```

But I am looking for a plot that shows x0 on the x-axis, y on the y-axis, all my data-points, and an estimated line showing the model b.

In order to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: OK, you want to plot the predictions vs x0? Then you need to decide on fixed values for the other predictors for this plot. I don't understand how such a plot would be useful.

Comment: Maybe this is not possible conceptually.. but I would like to see the relationship between x0 and y according to how the model sees it...

Comment: Yes, the predictions, could I see those, based on x0 on the x axis?

Comment: If you want to see the relationship between y and x0 (the contribution of x0 to y) that's exactly what the plot in your question shows you.

Comment: Ok, so when it says s(x0,2.5) on the y-axis. What does the 2.5 refer to? Would this be the estimated value for y? And do the ribbons indicate the range given the other variables x1-x3? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Zheyuan. I guess there is still the other variables that are contributing, so I can't show a full estimation. But this will work, if you want to post it as an answer...